# trying to get my jquery code to understand my unique ids

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a character countdown script in each of my 'reviews'. When the user clicks 'Edit'- the number decreases as the person types. Most they can put in is 200 characters.

Each 'review' has an id of `@review.id`

My reviews look like this:

[image]

The problem arises when I click 'Edit' in the 'review' below it, Review_2, or any other review (there can be many):

[image]

So, I'm having a problem separating/ giving a unique id in my code. My countdown script is (the div where the number appears is char_count_label):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()  {
    var characters = 200 -  $('textarea').val().length;
    $(".char_count_label").append(characters);
    $('textarea').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 200){
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, 200));
        }
    var remaining = 200 -  $(this).val().length;
    $(".char_count_label").html(remaining);
    });
});
</script>
```

And in my html/erb I have:

```
   <div class = "char_count_label">"</div>
```

I thought giving the specific review id in my code would do the trick like `<div class = "char_count_label" id="<%= @review.id %>"</div>`but it wasn't successful. Any ideas? Thanks!

I was asked to share my html with the textarea and the char_count_label so here it is!:

```
<div class="reviews">


    <div class="breadcrumb" id="review_51" style="height: 250px;">
<!-- Edit mode. Show this form, when user clicks the 'Edit' link> -->

<div class="edit_review_form">
  <div class="cancel-edit" id="51">

    <a href="/reviews/51" data-remote="true">Cancel</a>

  </div>

  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/reviews/51" class="simple_form edit_review" data-remote="true" id="edit_review_51" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="vzOYVqk9aSb7tOCUkhd8XbDRtwzRB4PLZ/L0xzsNPcE="></div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <div id="except_comment">


      <div class="control-group string required"><label class="string required control-label edit_form_titles" for="review_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Name</label><div class="label-error"></div><div class="controls"><input class="string required" id="review_name" name="review[name]" size="50" type="text" value="11"></div></div>

      <div class="control-group string optional"><label class="string optional control-label edit_form_titles" for="review_address">Address</label><div class="label-error"></div><div class="controls"><input class="string optional" id="review_address" name="review[address]" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){return false;}" placeholder="Enter address, town or village where you live." size="50" type="text" value="Baldoyle"></div></div>
      <span id="address_validation"></span>

      <div class="control-group tel optional"><label class="tel optional control-label" for="review_phone">Phone</label><div class="label-error"></div><div class="controls"><input class="string tel optional" id="review_phone" name="review[phone]" size="50" type="tel" value=""></div></div>
      </div>


      <div class="control-group text optional"><label class="text optional control-label comments" for="review_comment">Comments:</label><div class="label-error"></div><div class="controls"><textarea class="text optional" cols="40" id="review_comment" maxlength="300" name="review[comment]" rows="2" wrap="soft">public</textarea></div></div>

<div class="char_count_label">194</div>

        <!-- buttons: save, delete, share, keep private -->
      <div class="edit_button_group">


etc...
```

Comment: can you share the html portion with both the textarea and `char_count_label`

Comment: the problem is instead of using `$(".char_count_label")`, you need to find out the `char_count_label` which is next to the textarea

Comment: hi there, I added my html.erb. Hm, I'll investigate how to make it recognise the exact char_count_label. thanks.

Comment: i would like to see the generated html than the erb file...

Comment: You mean the html generated when I click F12 in Chrome? Right, will put it up now...

Comment: So much code! I think I have added the relevant stuff and got rid of the junk.

Comment: checkout my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `char_count_label` is the next sibling of the `textarea`s closest `control-group` element

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    var characters = 200 -  $('textarea').val().length;
    $(".char_count_label").append(characters);
    $('textarea').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 200){
            $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, 200));
        }
        var remaining = 200 -  $(this).val().length;
        $(this).closest('.control-group').next(".char_count_label").html(remaining);
    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! That's solved. But when I click 'Edit' on subsequent reviews, the number in the current review is added to the reviews above. So review1 has say '191', I open review2 which has '140' and then review1 says '191140', I open review3 which has '120' and review1 becomes '191140120' and reviews becomes '140120'...etc..Head wrecking stuff!Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Fixed by adding '$(this).closest('.control-group').next(".char_count_label").append(characters);' instead of '$(".char_count_label").append(characters);' in '$(document).ready(function()'

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `keyup` handler, you're querying the *entire* document for `.char_count_label` elements when what you really want to do is update the `.char_count_label` element that's associated with your `<textarea>`.

Instead of

```
$(".char_count_label").html(remaining);
```

try

```
$(this).next('.char_count_label').html(remaining);
```

It's hard to know how to query the `.char_count_label` in your particular case because you have not shown the HTML you're using, but the gist of my point is you want a reference to a single instance of `.char_count_label`, not *all* instances like you're currently doing.

Comment: Tried your code but it didn't work. I see what you mean though and I'll play around with your idea. Thanks! - added my html.erb, if that's any help.